# How to replace a pattern of string?

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have this input string:

```
Hello <foo> context61 Hi: context:file/  hello context715: context666:file/ foo
```

My goal is *replace* (clean) every occurrence of `context[anything]:` to an empty string. the `anything` part could be empty.

Output should look like this:

```
Hello <foo> context61 Hi: file/  hello  file/ foo
```

I have tried endless attempts but I'm just a noob when it comes to regex. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give a try to  the following vbscript code:

```
str="Hello <foo> context61 Hi: context:file/  hello context715: context666:file/ foo"
Set oreg = New RegExp
oreg.IgnoreCase=False
oreg.Global=True
oreg.Pattern="context\d*\:"                'context followed by 0 or more digits followed by colon
'oreg.Pattern="context[a-zA-Z0-9]*?\:"     'or we can have this as pattern which will cover alphabets too
result = oreg.Replace(str,"")              'replaces every matched pattern in the string 'str' by an empty string
MsgBox result
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: "Set matches = oreg.Execute(str)" is not necessary.

Comment: @RegisDesrosiers You are correct. I was testing the matches first. Forgot to remove it. I will update the code.

Comment: "oreg.IgnoreCase=False" could also be removed also because .IgnoreCase is false by default.

Comment: Thanks! you are a god.

Comment: You are welcome. No Sir, I make mistakes, hence not a God :P

Comment: @Kira, BTW, would it be more efficient to first test? e.g.: `If oreg.Test(str) Then oreg.Replace...`

Comment: @zig Yes, By using an If statement you can first test if a match is there or not. If it returns true, then replace otherwise don't replace. However, the current code won't throw you an error even if there are no matches.